# How to get rid of unnecessary field (relation) from collection of Eloquent models?

Tags: php, laravel

I've fetched bunch of models `::with('something')`. I have a collection of these models with eager loaded collection. I've performed some operation on this collection and now I don't need this relation in my final JSON output.

How can I get rid of it?

```
return Foo::with(['something'])->get(['id', 'content', 'target']);
```

When I return JSON response I get 4 columns (id, content, target and something). I want 3 columns. How to get rid of `something` before the final return of response?

[Which method should I use?](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections)

```
#relations: array:1 [
   "something" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1225
```

EDIT:

```
->each(function (Foo $foo) {
   unset($foo['something']);
})
->values();
```

This does the job but it doesn't look nice. Is there a better way?

Comment: Does hidding the attributes in the model would works for you? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Answer (score 1):

You can `map` (`each` accessor) the content and `hide` the relation:

```php
return Foo::with(['something'])
    ->get(['id', 'content', 'target'])
    ->each->makeHidden('something');
```

Your method might work, but IMO it's not the best option, because if you (for example, in the future) will change the code, and manipulate the relation after the `unset`, then you might encounter some troubles, where instead `hide` is just "hiding" the relation (you can do the same with attributes) from the serialization

You can find the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json)
If it's not clear why and how `->each->...` works, check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `transform` method of laravel collections.

```php
return Foo::with(['something'])->get()->transform(function($item, $key){
      return $item->only(['id', 'content', 'target']);
    });
```